# referencing belongs_to association of a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, belongs-to

I have the following relationships that work in the rails console but not when I run the site what I am doing wrong?

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :c

  def title
    a.title
  end
end
```

Table C has a foreign key to B and B has a foreign key to A.

This works in the rails console.

```
c = C.find(12)
c.b.title
```

But it doesn't work when I run the site.

Here is the error I get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `title' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation:0x104feb5a0>):
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you use it within the site?

Comment: Did you just mistype the `a` symbol? That should be `:a` not `a:`

Comment: I fixed the a: typo and added the actual error I get.

Comment: Are the two models owning the foreign key? If not, you should use a has_one somewhere!

Comment: Table C has a foreign key to B and B has a foreign key to A.

Comment: Do you have class A defined? If not, you must define it for the association to work. If so, please add it to your example.

Comment: I think you've abstracted away too much of your actual code, and possibly the bug along with it.  If you could post the 2 models (just their definitions and relationships, no unrelated methods needed) along with their definitions from schema.rb, we'd have everything we need to figure out the association error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to turn the class B title method into a class method to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than defining a method to do this, `delegate`! In `app/models/c.rb`:

```
delegate :title, :to => :b
```

And then in `app/models/b.rb`:

```
delegate :title, :to => :a
```

Answer (score 0):

> has_one(association_id, options = {})
>   Specifies a one-to-one association
>   with another class. This method should
>   only be used if the other class
>   contains the foreign key. If the
>   current class contains the foreign
>   key, then you should use belongs_to
>   instead. See also
>   ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods’s
>   overview on when to use has_one and
>   when to use belongs_to.

Comment: I forgot to add the has_many association in my question originally.